# Validation errors not displaying

Tags: expresso-store

I'm not sure what I've done wrong here but with this code, I don't get any validation taking place, it goes straight to the next step:

```
{exp:store:checkout
    next="checkout/payment"
    error_handling="inline"
    require="shipping_name|shipping_address1|shipping_city|shipping_postcode|shipping_country"
    error_delimiters='<label class="error">|</label>'
}

    <section>

        <h1>1. Shipping</h1>

        <div class="fr {if error:shipping_name}error{/if}">
            <label class="fl" for="shipping_name">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="ff">
                {field:shipping_name} {error:shipping_name}
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

{/exp:store:checkout}
```

If I change the require parameter to remove the shipping_ from each field, the form reloads the current page, but no errors are output, so I'm a little stumped at this stage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably another error which isn't displaying.

Try removing `error_handling="inline"` from your checkout tag to see any errors which you may not have added inline error variables for in your template.

Comment: That makes no difference for me - it just goes onto the next step. If I remove change the rules from shipping_, I do get errors for missing billing fields, but this is just a shipping page, so I just need to validate the shipping fields 'shipping_name|shipping_address1|shipping_city|shipping_postcode|shipping_country'.

Comment: Shipping fields don't get validated if you have 'shipping same as billing' set.

Comment: In config or in the template? I don't have that in the template and the Default Shipping Address is set to None in the module config. Still no validation either with or without inline errors.

Comment: Very odd. I'm not sure what's changed but it's now validating fine. I had continued working on the templates and CSS so must have fixed an error inadvertently!

Answer (score 1):

I have validation working perfectly on Store v2.0.3. Here is my code:
**http://pastie.org/private/qs9a9hhzfndkbhk8bsr4g**

Try popping it into your template... Just change the `next="checkout/step2"` parameter to your correct template name.

Comment: Thanks, I am only validating shipping fields (not both billing and shipping) and it's in this scenario that the problem occurs for me.